# Convert Safari to Go files to ePub

Tags: ebook-reader, epub

[Safari to Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.safaribooksonline) stores offline bag files in `\data\com.safaribooksonline\files\zips`. Each book has it's own directory with files that make up the entire book (xhtml, metadata, etc). Has anyone tried converting these files into ePub?

Safari to Go cuts off the bottom of the pages (i.e. cannot read full content). That's why I want to convert it to ePub instead. If not, is there any other way to read *Safari to Go* content?

Comment: Leaving this question open. Seems like a valid concern, and the problem is well-described.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files to a Windows/Mac or Linux machine and zip them one book directory at a time.  Then use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert them to just about any format you would like or another epub to .lit converter.

*You may need to rename the .zip files to .epub for them to be recognised.*